# Why is scrapy crawling a different facebook page and Why is the file empty?

Tags: python, scrapy

This is a scrapy spider.This spider is supposed to collect the names of all div nodes with class attribute=5d-5 essentially making a list of all people with x name from y location but the file created is empty.Here is the code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

class fb_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name="fb"
    allowed_domains = ["facebook.com"]
    start_urls = [             
    "https://www.facebook.com/search/people/?q=jaslyn%20california"]

     def parse(self,response):
         x=response.xpath('//div[@class="_5d-5"]'.extract())
         with open("asdf.txt",'wb') as f:
             f.write(u"".join(x).encode("UTF-8"))
```

In the command prompt I see a line:

```
    2016-08-14 12:06:57 [scrapy] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q=jaslyn%20california>
    2016-08-14 12:06:58 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

it says forbidden by robots.txt something is fishy about that.The URL is not the same as the URL I programmed it to crawl.

I upgraded settings.py to ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False but the spider still crawled a slightly different page from the URL specified.
Now I get :

```
2016-08-14 12:55:37 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q=jaslyn%20california> (referer: None)
 2016-08-14 12:55:38 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q=jaslyn%20california> (referer: None)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
 File "C:\Users\admin\Downloads\dist\Scrapy-1.1.1\scrapy\fb\fb\spiders\fbspider.py", line 15, in parse
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: As it's written you never call `parse()`. Even if you do have more code though, are you sure you're looking in the right directory?

Comment: Try searching your user profile for "asdf.txt" file, in your file browser. Like @Suever said, you're not calling parse. Why not copy-paste all your code?

Comment: why would u say i am not calling parse() ? scrapy executes the instructions in the parse by itself.A similar program extracting body elements from a different website worked.

Comment: I always found easier to use `open('asdf.txt', 'a').close()` to create files on script `__init__` and then just re-open it to write on it whenever it's needed.

Comment: tried f=open("asdf.txt",wb) still gives an invalid syntax error at f

Comment: That's because `x=response.xpath` is missing a closing parentheses

Comment: thank you!!! but the file still doesn't get created.